# How can I collect the information sendmail sends to a milter and receives from that milter?

Tags: centos, email, smtp, sendmail, milter

SendMail | CentOS

For debugging/troubleshooting purposes, I'd like to examine the raw information that sendmail is sending to a local milter (and also the data being returned by a milter).  Is that possible?  Would I be able to see this if I changed confLOG_LEVEL to maximum?

Answer (score 1):

You can install one of two milters right before the milter you want to check:

1- Install MIMEDefang and then write your own version of the [filter_*](http://linux.die.net/man/5/mimedefang-filter) routines so as to log anything you need, the way you need it.

2- Modify and install [sample_milter](http://www.acme.com/software/sample_milter/) to achieve the same purpose.

Just make sure that any of the two milters that you install do not alter or reject any incoming message.